# How to know which websocket version the client uses?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, version, websocket

I wrote a (not-so-)simple websocket server in python, which listens in a port, performs the handshaking and then sends to the client a sequence of messages (spaced out a random interval), containing numbers.

I wrote a javascript client and tested it under Chrome and Safari. I discovered that Chrome and Safari use different WebSocket versions. For example, Chrome uses Sec-WebSocket-Key (and expects Sec-WebSocket-Accept), while Safari sends instead Sec-WebSocket-Key1, Sec-WebSocket-Key2 and a bunch of 8 bytes after the header.

I implemented in the server a handshake function which detects the kind of handshake required, and performs it. This issue is solved. The websocket is correctly open from Chrome or Safari (both OSX, Windows and IOS5 versions).

But I have another problem. Apparently, Safari sends and expects messages delimited by 0x00 and 0xFF, while Chrome sends and expects framed and masked data (using a more recent version of the websocket specification).

I want to have a single server, which adapts himself to the expectations of the client. My question is, how can I tell in advance if the data has to be sent framed or 0x00,0xFF delimited?

I guess I could assume that, if the handshake protocol is based in Key1 and Key2, the client is Safari, and then use 0x00 0xFF to delimit data, while if it uses Sec-WebSocket-Key the client is Chrome, and then use framed data. However I'm not satisfied with this solution, since it is not general. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are published standards for both the [hixie-76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) protocol variant used by Safari (desktop & mobile) and [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) used by Chrome and others.

You can use the type of handshake requested to decide which protocol version a client speaks, what framing will exist on message reads and what framing you should use on message writes.

Comment: Thank you for the links. If I understood correctly, there is no "WebSocket-Version" or similar header, and I should then write ad-hoc code to manually detect the version used, right?

Comment: That's correct.  (There is a version header in later drafts of the RFC but there's no appropriate header available in both Chrome and Safari.)  I have a simple websocket server which uses the Sec-WebSocket-Key1 header to infer hixie-76 (Safari) and the Sec-WebSocket-Key header to infer RFC 6455 (Chrome).

Comment: This is not correct. For anything >= Hybi.10, the header is sent by Chrome, Firefox, WebKit Nightly, IE10 .. Sec-WebSocket-Version. They do send 8 or 13. This header isn't present for old Hixie-76 though .. but the only one still on that deprecated version is Safari. Webkit Nightly has RFC6455.

Have a look: http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/reports/clients/index.html

Click Case 1.1.1 for different browser and scroll down to WebSocket handshake.

Disclaimer: I am author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: @oberstet, the original question was about how to write a websocket server which can speak to Chrome and Safari (desktop & mobile).  I thought many iOS browsers still spoke Hixie-76.  Are you saying that iOS uses Hybi-10+ now?  If so, do you know which version this started on?  (I've looked at your web page but this information isn't immediately obvious from it.)

Comment: No, WebKit _Nightly_ (as of March 2012) speaks RFC6455. If and when that makes it to iOS I dunno.

Comment: It is sufficient to assume that the lack of a Sec-WebSocket-Version header implies Hixie76/Hybi00. There are no implementations of Hybi01-06 in the wild. Hybi07-RFC6455 have the version header.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question, as i had the same need, i found that the window.WebSocket.CLOSED equals to 3 in the latest implementation when on older one, it equals to 2 (Android native browser by example).

So the test i now make to detect support of the latest WebSocket protocol is :

```
if('WebSocket' in window
    &&'function' === typeof window.WebSocket
    &&3 === window.WebSocket.CLOSED) {
// hurra !
}
```

I tested it in Chrome, Firefox (where it succeed) and on the Android Browser (where it fails). Wish it will help some people there.

Answer (score -1):

Simple: the is only one version of WebSockets. The rest are drafts. Now that the RFC is out, you're officially recommended not to implement anything else. The latest versions of Firefox and Chrome both implement the RFC version, and they auto-update. The drafts will stop being used by clients very quickly, so there's no point trying to implement them even to gain a little more interoperability.

They're not relevant anymore, and add cruft. It's not intended going forward by any of the browser vendors that the drafts should continue to be supported. Indeed, Mozilla waited until the spec before unprefixing their websocket object. Similarly, the browser vendors were clear that any applications written for drafts should be demos, not production code, and there's no expectation that they'll support draft servers any more than they support draft client code.

So, stick to the one spec, and forget about the early implementations of the drafts.

Comment: Not really an option if you want to run on mobile.

Comment: Agreed with @kybernetikos. Until the mobile browsers come out with versions that adopt the latest protocol, you're stuck with needing to support the older protocol concurrently with the current protocol.